# How to write a create table statement for MySQL using Java where the name of the table is a string?

Tags: java, mysql

My question is very simple. I just want to know how to write a create Table statement for MySQL using Java statements where the name of the table is a string.

I know how to insert String values as values of the coloumns using Java. I tried it that way but could not do it. I will show you my code:

```
String table = "CREATE TABLE table_name'" +
                               "(SL. No INT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                               " NAME VARCHAR(100), " + 
                               " YEAR INT not NULL, " + 
                               " IMDB INT not NULL)";
```

Here instead of table_name I want to input a string variable. The variable name is s2.

Now the Insert into table value is as follows:

```
myStmt.executeUpdate("insert into l1(id,email,usname,pwd)value('"+(i)+"','"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s5+"')");
```

Here s1,s2,s5 are string values. But this method is not working for Create Table and it is showing syntax error. What is the correct code?

Comment: `"CREATE TABLE table_name'" +` There is an unwanted single quote here.

Comment: You should use Prepared Statements to avoid SQL injections.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You can concat your table string just like you do it for insert string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove additional `'` sign and change name for SL. No column to somethin else so it looks like

```
String table = "CREATE TABLE table_name" +
            "(slno INT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
            " NAME VARCHAR(100), " +
            " YEAR INT not NULL, " +
            " IMDB INT not NULL)"
```

If your table string is correct you can replace table_name with new name for each table with replace method on string or just use function

```
public static String getCreateTableQuery(String tableName) {
    String table = "CREATE TABLE table_name" +
            "(slno INT not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
            " NAME VARCHAR(100), " +
            " YEAR INT not NULL, " +
            " IMDB INT not NULL)";

    String createTableWithNewNameQuery = table.replaceFirst("table_name'", tableName);
    return createTableWithNewNameQuery;
}
```